# R - Iterate through a Data Frame using for Loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to generate the below series (see attached image) based on the logic given below. I was able create the series for one product and store (code given below). i am having trouble when i try to generalize this for multiple product store combinations. Could you please advise if there is an easier way to do this.

## Logic

```
a     given
b     lag of d by 4
c     initial c for first week thereafter (c previous row + b current - a current)
d     initial d - c current
```

## my code

```
library(dplyr)

df = structure(list(
  Product = c(11078931, 11078931, 11078931, 11078931, 11078931, 
              11078931, 12021216, 12021216, 12021216, 12021216, 
              12021216, 12021216, 10932270, 10932270, 10932270, 
              10932270, 10932270), 
  STORE = c(90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 547, 547, 
            547, 547, 547), 
  WEEK = c(201627, 201628, 201629, 201630, 201631, 201632, 201627, 201628, 
           201629, 201630, 201631, 201632, 201627, 201628, 201629, 201630, 
           201631), 
  WEEK_SEQ = c(914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 
               914, 915, 916, 917, 918), 
  a = c(9.161, 9.087, 8.772, 8.698, 7.985, 6.985, 0.945, 0.734, 0.629, 0.599, 
        0.55, 0.583, 5.789, 5.694, 5.488, 5.47, 5.659), 
  initial_d = c(179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 37, 37, 
                37, 37, 37), 
  Initial_c = c(62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 59, 0, 0, 0, 0)
), 
.Names = c("Product", "STORE", "WEEK", "WEEK_SEQ", "a", "initial_d", 
           "Initial_c"), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L))

# filter to extract one product and store
# df = df %>% filter(Product == 11078931) %>% filter(STORE == 90)



df$b = 0 
df$c = 0 
df$d = NA

c_init = 62
d_init = 179
df$d <- d_init
df$c[1] <- c_init

RQ <- function(df,...){

for(i in seq_along(df$WEEK_SEQ)){
  if(i>4){
    df[i, "b"] =  round(df[i-4,"d"], digits = 0)# Calculate b with the lag
  }
  if(i>1){
    df[i, "c"] =  round(df[i-1, "c"] + df[i, "b"] - df[i, "a"], digits = 0) # calc c
  }
  df[i, "d"] <- round(d_init - df[i, "c"], digits = 0) # calc d
  if(df[i, "d"] < 0) {
    df[i, "d"] <- 0 # reset negative d values
  }
}


  return(df)

}

df = df %>% group_by(SKU_CD, STORE_CD) %>% RQ(df)
```

[Expected output series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLmgj.png)

could you please advice what is wrong in my code. this code works fine for one product and store combination. but for multiple product and store it doesn't. thanks for your time and input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider base R's `by` which subsets the input dataframe by each combination of factor types to return a list of the subsetted dataframes. Then, run a `do.call(rbind, ...)` to row bind the list into one final dataframe.

```
RQ_dfs <- by(df, df[c("Product", "STORE")], FUN=RQ)
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, RQ_dfs)
```

While I cannot achieve your outputted series screenshot with posted data, the filtered commented out pairing does show up `finaldf`:

```
# # A tibble: 17 × 10
#     Product STORE   WEEK WEEK_SEQ     a initial_d Initial_c     b     c     d
# *     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  11078931    90 201627      914 9.161       179        62     0    62   117
# 2  11078931    90 201628      915 9.087       179         0     0    53   126
# 3  11078931    90 201629      916 8.772       179         0     0    44   135
# 4  11078931    90 201630      917 8.698       179         0     0    35   144
# 5  11078931    90 201631      918 7.985       179         0   117   144    35
# 6  11078931    90 201632      919 6.985       179         0   126   263     0
# 7  12021216    90 201627      914 0.945        18        33     0     0   179
# 8  12021216    90 201628      915 0.734        18         0     0    -1   180
# 9  12021216    90 201629      916 0.629        18         0     0    -2   181
# 10 12021216    90 201630      917 0.599        18         0     0    -3   182
# 11 12021216    90 201631      918 0.550        18         0   179   175     4
# 12 12021216    90 201632      919 0.583        18         0   180   354     0
# 13 10932270   547 201627      914 5.789        37        59     0     0   179
# 14 10932270   547 201628      915 5.694        37         0     0    -6   185
# 15 10932270   547 201629      916 5.488        37         0     0   -11   190
# 16 10932270   547 201630      917 5.470        37         0     0   -16   195
# 17 10932270   547 201631      918 5.659        37         0   179   157    22
```

Comment: I probably would have never come up with such a sophisticated solution. thank you very much you helped me big time!

Comment: @Sam...Glad to help! I find `by` is an overlooked worthwhile function that even I ignore for other data wrangling workarounds.